# Javascript errors, can someone help me?

Tags: javascript, html

i need some help with my javascript.

I want it to countdown everytime you click the img and i want the image to change on some numbers, but nothing works
This is the script.

*In the console i get this 2 errors 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Uncaught ReferenceError: clicks is not defined*

```
**Code**

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script language="javascript">
            var num=1000;
            var end=false;

            function clicks(){
                    negative();
                    bajs();
                    parseInt(document.getElementById("count").innerHTML);
            }

            function negative(){
                if(end==false){
                    num-=1;
                    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML=("<strong style="color:red;">Egg Health:</strong> " + num);
                }

            }

            function bajs()
            {
                if(num==890){
                document.getElementById("pappa").src=("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68415431/egg1.png");
                }

                if(num==650){
                document.getElementById("pappa").src=("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68415431/egg2.png");
                }

                if(num==490){
                document.getElementById("pappa").src=("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68415431/egg3.png");
                }

                if(num==99){
                document.getElementById("pappa").src=("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68415431/egg4.png");
                }

                if(num==0){
                document.getElementById("pappa").src=("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68415431/toy.png");
                end=true;
                }
            }



        </script>
        <center>

        <div style="width:500px; height:900px; background-color:gold; border-radius:10px;">
            <br>
            <h2><u>Lets eat a kinder egg!</u></h2>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <span id="count"><strong style="color:red;">Egg Health: </strong>1000</span>
            <br>
            <i style="font-size:10px;">Click da egg</i>
            <br>
            <a href="#" onclick="clicks()"><img id="pappa" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68415431/egg.png" /></a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>Made by me in 1 second</p>
            </div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `center` tag doesn't exist in HTML5. It was deprecated in HTML 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put simple quote or escape the double quotes in :

```
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML=('<strong style="color:red;">Egg Health:</strong> ' + num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though `Mibou` is right up there I would give you another hint
Normally I distinguish between the static and dynamic part that I have.

In your example 
    Egg Health: 1000
The only part that I modify is the number in JS, So why keep on creating the whole thing again and again, might just handle the dynamic part and leave the static part as it is.

Here is what I modified in your script,

In JS, function negative

```
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = num;
```

in HTML

```
<span><strong style="color:red;">Egg Health: </strong><span id="count">1000</span></span>
```

Happy Coding :)